# Windows programming (GUI): Empty tab is not displayed when program is launched

Tags: excel, windows, vba, user-interface, tabs

Right now, I am working on a project handed over to me by someone else. There, a GUI with several tabs has been created (four in total). Three of these tabs contain various buttons, textboxes, etc. But the fourth tab does not contain anything for now (but I can see it in the editor).

If I now launch the program, I can see the first three tabs, but the fourth tab isn’t even displayed (although it even has a *name* which is displayed properly in the editor).

I have commented out everything else so that I can just run the program with its “naked” GUI. So: Where is the problem?

Comment: Each tab in a TabPage has a *.visible* property, click the 4th tab in the designer and make sure its visibility is set to *true* in its properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Alex, the `Visible` property of your sheet is probably not True. `Visible` can have 3 values for a Workheet:

- `-1` or `xlSheetVisible` or `True`: The worksheet tab is visible in Excel
- `0` or `xlSheetHidden` or `False`: The worksheet tab is not visible, but can be shown using the context menu and selecting Unhide
- `2` or `xlSheetVeryHidden`: The worksheet tab is not visible, and cannot be shown using the context menu and selecting Unhide. The worksheet can be accessed only by program.